# One-time-only password

Tags: security, passwords

I want to apply a constraint to the password reset option that the new password is always unique from the one which was ever set for this user account. So that a user could never be able to reuse an older password while using the reset option.

Now, I want to get an opinion what pros and cons could this restriction have from the security point of view and from the user usability point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Pros:

1. User is not able to recycle former passwords, so any previous compromise will ostensibly not allow future compromise.

Cons:

1. User will make small variations to an old password to make it easier to remember, so you do not gain much in terms of extra entropy in the password.
2. One malicious user could attack you with resource exhaustion by constantly changing their password, because you allocate resources to store all old passwords.